# Visual Studio not installing extensions, even when all instances are closed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to install an extension from the Visual Studio 2022 Manage Extension window.

It says I have to close all Visual Studio windows, which I did, but it is still not installing.

Comment: Did you try the "standard Windows solution?"  (The standard solution is: Do a reboot, and then retry)

Comment: @Luuk Yes I did, I already had this problem yesterday, and I restarted 3 times or so.

Comment: @11_22_33 Hi, any update about this issue?

Comment: @11_22_33, How about running your VS as the admin? Make sure that your VS2022 was the latest version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview?view=vs-2022, test it again. If no help, please share the extension name you want to install or try to install other extension, check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this the *bad* way

I basically just reinstalled Windows (I would not recommend you to do this, you should always search for a different solution first). I backed everything up, of course.

Answer (score 0):

What extension did you install? You can try to download the extension from the [MarketPlace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).